# Spring Eureka Client does not see server port from configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have an application based on spring-boot which is deployed to jar. It has a form of  maven multi-module project and contains following parts:

- web
- service
- repository
- model

My web module needs all others to build itself and contains in its resource directory following file:

- bootstrap.yml

The bootstrap.yml contains following configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    eureka-server-port: 8761
server:
  port: 8763
  context-path: /foo-service/rest
spring:
  application:
    name: foo-service
```

So I am expecting that during wake up it will use port 8761 and register itself to Eureka service. Because of some reason when I debug at:

```
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration#eurekaInstanceConfigBean
```

the instance of EurekaInstanceConfigBean contains following values:

- instanceId = 172.20.39.197:foo-service:8763
- ***nonSecurePort = 8080***

What is weird is **nonSecurePort** set on 8080 instead of 8763. In my other services (which works correctly) the **nonSecurePort** has the same value as last part of **instanceId**. Only in foo-service the value is different.

The reason of that is:

```
@Value("${server.port:${SERVER_PORT:${PORT:8080}}}")
int nonSecurePort;
```

can't find the configuration and returns the default value. But why?
I have checked the foo.jar created by maven and the bootstrap.yml is there in correct place (BOOT-INF/classes/bootstrap.yml) with correct values...

Do anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I tried to create but all simple samples works for me. Only this, single and complex application does not work. When I manage to get more information immediately share here. But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was following:

The application had still some old properties loaded via xml:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("some-xml-file") // which loads properties
class FooConfig {}
```

The properties loaded by xml file did not have any port defined so for sure that was not the case of override. However seems it was enough to interfere somehow with Spring-Boot.

After small refactoring:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("properties-file") // loading properties without xml
class FooConfig {}
```

all started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Several boot applications built exactly the same way. Applications using **@ImportResource** register with an incorrect default port of 8080 with Eureka.

I could not move away from @ImportResource yet.

Adding the following to bootstrap.yml worked.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 8088
```